# jQuery not working with its components being color animations and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sql-update

I am a newbie to `jQuery` and I am trying to create a page with different colors, and when we click on any, it changes the background color of navigation bar and footer and uses ajax to update the `MYSQL` database.So here is my `jQuery` code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="personal_theme_color"]').click(function() {
        var a = $('[name="personal_theme_color"]').val();
        switch (a) {
          case "pink":
            var b = "#e91e63";
            break;

          case "purple":
            b = "#9c27b0";
            break;

          case "deep-purple":
            b = "#673ab7";
            break;

          case "indigo":
            b = "#3f51b5";
            break;

          case "light-blue":
            b = "#03a9f4";
            break;

          case "cyan":
            b = "#00bcd4";
            break;

          case "green":
            b = "#4caf50";
            break;

          case "light-green":
            b = "#8bc34a";
            break;

          case "lime":
            b = "#cddc39";
            break;

          case "yellow":
            b = "#ffeb3b";
            break;

          case "amber":
            b = "#ffc107";
            break;

          case "orange":
            b = "#ff9800";
            break;

          case "deep-orange":
            b = "#ff5722";
            break;

          case "brown":
            b = "#9e9e9e";
            break;

          case "grey":
            b = "#9e9e9e";
        }
        $(".nav-wrapper").animate({
            backgroundColor: b
        });
        $("footer").animate({
            backgroundColor: b
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jsp/update_user_theme.php",
            data: "theme=" + a,
            cache: false,
            success: function(a) {
                alert("Updated successfully");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So that's my code. I don't know what is the problem with it but I really need help. 
**Note:** I've already included the `jQuery` color animation plugins

And my `PHP` code:

```
<?php
    require_once('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/sp/conn.php');
    $theme = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, trim(htmlentities($_POST['theme'])));

    // Now update  query
    $query = "UPDATE user set theme = '$themecolor', hex2 = '$hex' WHERE id = '" . $_COOKIE['id'] . "'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
?>
```

**P.S.**I would really appreciate some help in the `PHP` code itself too, especially for making it `SQL` Injection-proof. Thank you in advance
Have a good day

**EDIT:** The HTML. I used `foreach` loop for getting those values from an array. But this html is hardcoded(from `view-source:` of chrome). See the differences in classes and values of label and input tags.:

```
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img pink waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      pink
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="pink" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img purple waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      purple
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="purple" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img deep-purple waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      deep-purple
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="deep-purple" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img indigo waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      indigo
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="indigo" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img blue waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      blue
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="blue" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img light-blue waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      light-blue
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="light-blue" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img cyan waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      cyan
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="cyan" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img green waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      green
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="green" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img light-green waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      light-green
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="light-green" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img lime waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      lime
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="lime" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img yellow waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      yellow
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="yellow" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img amber waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      amber
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="amber" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img orange waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      orange
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="orange" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img deep-orange waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      deep-orange
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="deep-orange" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img brown waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      brown
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="brown" />
</label>
<label class="personal_theme_label">
  <div class="style_personal_img grey waves-effect waves-light z-depth-1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <font style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      grey
    </font>
  </div>
  <input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" id="test1" value="grey" />
</label>
```

and also , my page's screenshot:
[This is how my page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8zzT.png)

Comment: What is the html for this element: `[name=\"personal_theme_color\"]`?

Comment: Provided the click actually selects the correct element, this line change to `var ptcval = $(this).val();` instead of `var ptcval = $("[name=\"personal_theme_color\"]").val();`

Comment: does the click function fire ?

Comment: @gypsyCoder what? If you are asking for js events then there aren't any in html as jquery has taken care of that

Comment: actually, I want to know, is the problem in tha ajax call or in the background color change or both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // CHANGE THIS LINE --> Try adding the "input" and remove the quotes (not 100% necessary)
    $("input[name=personal_theme_color]").click(function () {
        // CHANGE THIS LINE --> Use "$(this)" to localize the selection
        var ptcval = $(this).val();
        // ADD THIS LINE --> Make "var color" a preset
        // You could also just do "var color;"
        var color = "#FFF";

        switch (ptcval) {
            case "pink":
                // CHANGE THIS LINE --> adding "var color" here will only work if click "pink"
                color = '#e91e63';
                break;

            case "purple":
                color = '#9c27b0';
                break;

            case "deep-purple":
                color = "#673ab7";
                break;

            case "indigo":
                color = "#3f51b5";
                break;

            case "light-blue":
                color = "#03a9f4";
                break;

            case "cyan":
                color = "#00bcd4";
                break;

            case "green":
                color = "#4caf50";
                break;

            case "light-green":
                color = "#8bc34a";
                break;

            case "lime":
                color = "#cddc39";
                break;

            case "yellow":
                color = "#ffeb3b";
                break;

            case "amber":
                color = "#ffc107";
                break;

            case "orange":
                color = "#ff9800";
                break;

            case "deep-orange":
                color = "#ff5722";
                break;

            case "brown":
                color = "#9e9e9e";
                break;

            case "grey":
                color = "#9e9e9e";
                break;
        }

        $('.nav-wrapper').animate({
            backgroundColor : color
        });
        $('footer').animate({
            backgroundColor : color
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'jsp/update_user_theme.php',
            // CHANGE THIS LINE --> send an object instead of string
            data: { theme: ptcval },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Updated successfully');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**OPTION 2:**
A more intuitive method would be making a `data` attribute on the radio buttons that contain the hex value:

```
<input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" value="cyan" data-color="#00bcd4" />
<input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" value="pink" data-color="#e91e63" />
<input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" value="purple" data-color="#9c27b0" />
<input name="personal_theme_color" type="radio" class="with-gap" value="orange" data-color="#ff9800" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name=personal_theme_color]").click(function(e) {
            // Assign the object
            var thisObj =   $(this);
            // Extract the color from the data-color attribute
            var color   =   thisObj.data('color');
            // Get the value of the radio button
            var value   =   thisObj.val();
            // Assign the url
            var url     =   'jsp/update_user_theme.php';

            $('.nav-wrapper').animate({
                backgroundColor : color
            });
            $('footer').animate({
                backgroundColor : color
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: { theme: value },
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('Updated successfully');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the php side, you need to make sure the values use bind parameters (see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, I use PDO so I don't want to provide a jenky solution there):

```
<?php
    // I would suggest using __DIR__ relative to this file instead of the $_SERVER
    require_once(__DIR__.'/sp/conn.php');
    $theme = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, trim(htmlentities($_POST['theme'])));

    // You may want to use $_SESSION instead of $_COOKIE
    $query = "UPDATE user set theme = '$themecolor', hex2 = '$hex' WHERE id = '" . $_COOKIE['id'] . "'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: Like this way to explain

Answer (score 0):

I am adding one more thing my other mate already provide you the solution.

If you are not using binding param than you must need to use **mysqli_real_escape_string()** for your inputs like:

```
$theme = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['theme']);
$hex2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['hex2']);
$cookieID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['id']);
```